# AngularJS -- Show div only if touched and empty

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show a div only if the input field is touched and is still empty.

I have tried the following code, but the div doesnt not appear. For some reason it cannot read the touched state I think.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong ?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 mainbox" >
<form name="loginForm">
    <div class="spacing"></div>
      <h5>Please input your data:</h5>
      <input ng-model="vm.username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control input-md">
      <div class="spacing">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="!vm.username && vm.username.$touched">
              Please put your username!
          </div>
      </div>
      <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Κωδικός" class="form-control input-md">
      <div class="spacing"></div>
      <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right">Είσοδος</button>
</form>
```

PS. When i remove the $touched condition, the div is showing perfectly only if the input username is empty.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the $touched? Why not try using ngMouseover or ngMouseup  ... or some of those events ... and bind a variable that becomes true/false on any of them, then use that variable in your ng-if ... not sure what you're trying to do though

Comment: @Marko Just trying to show a div with alert when he touches the input field but leaves it without typing anything.

Comment: Yeah but what is a 'touch' event ? If its just angularJS web app, then thats ngMouseUp ...  so you can use the logic of binding a variable that will just change to true/false on that event

Comment: @Marko it may be a tab also..the question is how to make it work with $touched as i see the ng-touch class is applied to the field.

Comment: This what i mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219015/3690004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set name property to your input control to accomplish your task.
Also you need to access $touched like **loginForm.userName.$touched**

```
<form name="loginForm">
<div class="spacing"></div>
  <h5>Please input your data:</h5>
  <input ng-model="vm.username" name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control input-md">
  <div class="spacing">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="!vm.username && loginForm.userName.$touched">
          Please put your username!
      </div>
  </div>
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Κωδικός" class="form-control input-md">
  <div class="spacing"></div>
  <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right">Είσοδος</button>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Perfect answer, works that way. So you cannot use $touched with ng-model but only with name attributes, correct?

Comment: Yep you are correct. Please check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for more details. It would be great if you upvote too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` event on input field.

Look at this [pen](https://codepen.io/anuragasaurus/pen/jmoEpR)

Comment: Yap, that exactly what I meant in comment, just figure out what mouse event you want to use

Comment: The problem with this code is the message appears when you click inside before you type. The message should appear only if you have left the field and is still empty.